# Is having Multiple domains good or bad for seo?

Tags: domains, redirects

My company name is basically my last name plus the business type. Thats what my website address is but would it be good or bad for seo if i aquire the domain of the variations my business can go by and make them redirect to my primary domain?

Hope that makes sense

Thank you